# C reverse string

Tags: c

I have the following code where Index is defined as length- 1. It prints an extra space in the beginning if I dont include the - 1. Why is the -1 required in the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char s[200];
   int index, lenght;

   printf("Input a string\n");
   gets(s);

   // Calculating string length
   length = strlen(s);
    index=length-1;
   while (index >=0) {

    printf("%c", s[index]);
    index--;
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: string in C are zero index based....  time to read any of the standard C tutorials, perhaps?

Comment: Besides lua (ironically, under the hood the arrays that drive entire thing are obviously 0 based...) and few other niche languages you'll probably never use, arrays are always 0 based. So instead of indexes going from 1 to 10, they are 0 to 9, so to get last element of array with length 10, you use `length - 1`. You should learn about basic C types and syntax before trying to reverse strings and whatever else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes always start from `0`. So if strlen() function returns the length `x` that means its length is `x` and you have to iterate from 0 to `x-1`. Thats why you have to include `-1`. On index x there will be `\0`.

Comment: Thank you. I thought the reason was due to null terminator?!

Answer (score 1):

Let us take a string of length 5 -- `abcde`. `len` is 5.

```
while (index >=0) {
    printf("%c", s[index]);
    index--;
}
```

For the first element in the loop, you are printing `s[index]`. You want to print `e` i.e. `s[4]`

Therefore you need to set index as `len-1`

If not, you are printing `s[5]` which is `\0`, the NULL terminator.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that extra character in the beginning is that, the string is terminated with a NULL character. So if you store a string “abcdef” it will be stored as a,b,c,d,e,f,\0. Strlen will return the length of above string as 6. So if you start from printing array index 6, NULL is printed and so on. Hence the extra space. 
Using -1 makes you start printing from array index 5 (your data will be stored in array indexes 0-5) which is f in this case, so you need to use -1.